# Connecting a web application to a laser barcode reader

Tags: html, reactjs, spring, web

Now I am creating a web application with `React.js` in front-end and `Spring REST` in the back-end, and I want to read information from barcode with barcode scanner(Red laser scanning like in the image), and display the information received directly into my website

[image]

Comment: I found this npm library https://github.com/axenox/onscan.js/ . I am still trying to make it work

Comment: I was always under the impression that these things just behaved like fancy "keyboards", and sent the ASCII text for the barcode as keypresses --- if that's true (and I'm pretty sure it is, but not 100% certain) then you could just display a normal input box and deal with it like you would any other form data.